# Remove home page navigation from logo at checkout

Tags: 7, theming

Usually users can go to front/home page from anywhere by clicking on the logo. But if I see some e-commerce site, they restrict it when we go for any steps of checkout.
I also want to do the same. If somebody clicks on checkout & URL form something like $base_url/checkout*, I want to remove home/front page navigation link from logo.
How can it be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created three `page.tpl.php` with name - `page--checkout.tpl.php`, `page--checkout--review.tpl.php`, `page--checkout--shipping.tpl.php`.

These were being called on the every steps of checkout process in my instance.

After that everything was easy. I had control over each elements of page. I removed unwanted region as well as navigation to HOME from site logo.

Answer (score 2):

A good method of doing this is with the context module and context layouts.

Context module: https://drupal.org/project/context

You can specify two layouts, one for main and one for checkout.

Heres a vid about it. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzBpjZ_ZRfo

Comment: Two layout enable by creating different TPL for the purpose of mine need help of delta module. But it doesn't work without Omega....